# USB C Power delivery doesnt work properly

Tags: usb, charging, usb-c, voltage-source

I'm designing a 5V Power source for USB-C devices.
Based on [this hackaday article](https://hackaday.com/2023/01/04/all-about-usb-c-resistors-and-emarkers/) I've chosen 10k Pullup resistors between the CC lines and 5V to indicate that my source can supply up to 3A.
[image: USB-C Power supply shematic]

My power supply is a [RD-50A](https://www.meanwell-web.com/content/files/pdfs/productPdfs/MW/Rd-50/RD-50-spec.pdf), which can supply up to 6A @ 5V. The protection fuse is a [0ZCG0300FF2B](https://www.belfuse.com/resources/datasheets/circuitprotection/ds-cp-0zcg-series.pdf) with 3A holding current and 5A tripping current.

When I connect this source to a samsung tablet it seems to charge but I get a yellow warning triangle: [Example from reddit](https://www.reddit.com/media?url=https%3A%2F%2Fpreview.redd.it%2Fdj0tv4kelxl81.jpg%3Fauto%3Dwebp%26s%3Dad4898b8bc436364d227681479b9886d15cf96d3).

Do you have any idea whats wrong?

Kind regards
Dennis

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most modern USB devices would like to communicate with the power supply to get more than 5V. With USB Type-C, USB-PD communication can be used, but there are also other methods.

Your design does not allow any kind of communication and can't give more than 5V, even if it signals to the device that 3A at 5V is available. The device can't use 5V at 3A as it is designed for higher voltage or higher power charging and will only charge slowly or not at all.

And that is why you get a warning about non-optimal charging. Your charger does not communicate USB-PD or any other protocol and does not support higher voltages and higher power.

Besides your implementation is wrong and dangerous.

It is not allowed to have 5V supply present on a USB Type-C receptacle until a connection to another device is detected/negotiated and it is determined safe to turn supply on.

If someone accidentally plugs in a PC or laptop with Type-A to Type-C cable to your charger, it likely gets damaged.

USB specifications are made to require that damage is not possible when devices are designed and made according to the specification.

Also most of the things in this answer is also stated in the article you linked.